# I want to keep first image selected when I load this page

Tags: jquery

http://designpoodles.com/avtex/radio_pictures/

I want to keep first image selected when I load this page.

Comment: Post relevant HTML and code here at SO. Why should one visits your site? currently its nothing more than a spam

Comment: If you want persistant data between requests, you'll need to store the data in a `session` variable or in a `database` with `PHP`, in a `cookie` with `jQuery` or use `localStorage` in javascript but I've never used it.

Comment: This is completed unresearched, voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

In document ready call click function of first image.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#category_fruit").click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

while page load `trigger('click')` is the function that will call it when page loads

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#category_fruit").trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to explain what the code does, even thought its obvious for experienced programmers.

Comment: Sorry this code is not working.This code is not keeping the radio selected on load.